# Save and manage a volley queue in android

Tags: android, background, singleton, android-volley

I'm using a volley queue for HTTP requests.
I was thinking about saving and managing the queue in a singleton (my API manager), but I was told that there is a risk that android destroys it or the data it holds (the queue) if its out of memory.

Someone offered to use a fragment without a UI in order to use its "savedInstanceState" and when the fragment will be recreated, I won't lose the data.

It seems to me like there should be a different way to save and manage this queue in a background thread (and not an activity) and still be sure the data won't get lost.

Thanks,
Maayan

Answer (score 0):

I am managing volley queue in singleton extended from Application. This is used very often. If this Application singleton is destroyed by android, then all fragments and activities are destroyed too, that means complete app. This happens very rare on old low HW phones if app is in background and system needs to free memory